# empty, zero and non-zero pixels representation in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot ray traced path where pixel value gets non "-1" value  in matplotlib. In other words, I have following 2D array which represents 4 rays paths. Each pixel crossed by ray has random value. Except these intersected pixels, the rest of them are "-1". I want to show value "-1" in a white color or non-visible (no exist). How is it possible?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pylab as pl

M = np.array([[ 0. , -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
          [ 0.25, -1.,-1.,-1.,-1.,-1.],
          [ 0.25, -1., -1., -1.,-1.,-1.],
          [ 0.22, -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1.],
          [ 0.16, -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1.],
          [ 0.16, -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1.],
          [ 0.13, -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1.],
          [ 0.10, -1., -1., -1., -1.,-1.],
          [-1., 0.06, 0.14, 0.087, 0.079,0.],
          [ 0., 0.16, 0.10, 0.15, 0.16, 0.],
          [-1., -1., 0., 0.004,-1., -1.]])

pl.subplot(111)
pl.imshow(M, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternate way to do this is to use the `set_under`, `set_over` and `set_bad` properties of color maps [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap)

```
from copy import copy

# normalize data between vmin and vmax
my_norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=.25, vmax=.75, clip=False)
# clip=False is important, if clip=True, then the normalize function
# clips out of range values to 0 or 1 which defeats what we want to do here.

my_cmap = copy(cm.get_cmap('gray')) # make a copy so we don't mess up system copy
my_cmap.set_under('r', alpha=.5) # make locations over vmax translucent red
my_cmap.set_over('w', alpha=0)   # make location under vmin transparent white
my_cmap.set_bad('g')             # make location with invalid data green

test_data = np.random.rand(10, 10) # some random data between [0, 1]
test_data[5, 5] = np.nan           # add one NaN
# plot!
imshow(test_data, norm=my_norm, cmap=my_cmap, interpolation='nearest')
```

[image: Example output]

I would argue this is a better way than making a mask array by hand as you let `matplotlib` do the work for you and it lets you explicitly set the color of the three different conditions independently.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a masked array. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html

```
>>> masked = np.ma.masked_where(M==-1,M)
>>> pl.subplot(111)
>>> pl.imshow(masked, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
>>> pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Berni, will it also work in this cases??                                 `plt.imshow(Masked, origin='lower', cmap = pl.cm.cmapname('jet') interpolation='nearest')`

Comment: Sure. You can do `import matplotlib.cm as cm` and then `pl.imshow(masked, origin='lower', cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest')`